# FFmpeg: Can't read self-rendered videofile with QTRLE

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decode, encode

I adjusted the decoding_encoding.c example to use the ARGB pixel format, the QTRLE codec and a live stream.
I can successfully write my video stream to a file but can't access the stream again properly.
I tried something like this:

```
if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, src_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    exit(1);
}

/* retrieve stream information */
if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
    exit(1);
}

av_dump_format(fmt_ctx, 0, src_filename, 0);
```

similiar to what's written in the demuxing_decoding.c- and the filtering_video.c-example.

This results in the program trying to use the AAC-code which obviously fails:

```
Initializing ...[aac @ 001d4d60] Format aac detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[aac @ 001d59a0] channel element 0.0 is not allocated
[aac @ 001d59a0] Reserved bit set.
...
```

Similiarly, I can't get FFplay to correctly detect the codec; and when using

```
ffplay -formats
```

it doesn't even list qtrle there.

Do I have to use a mux to properly use qtrle? I'm confused because the decoding_encoding.c-example doesn't seem to use any mux but simply sets the codec and everything works ... ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't save audio, only video (sorry for not mentioning that earlier).

Comment: ffmpeg -codecs should list qtrle. Anyway my guess is some type of finalization needs to happen but isn't in your code, that's about all I can think of, GL!

Comment: ffmpeg -codecs does list qtrle, but ffplay does not; that's why I wondered whether I would need to use a mux as a container format?